# removing extension from file without knowing it

Tags: bash

I know how to remove the extension of a file, when I know it as:

```
nameis=$(basename $dataset .csv)
```

but I want to remove any extension without knowing it beforehand, anyone know how to do this?

Any help appreciated,
Ted

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In bash you can do the following:

```
nameis=${dataset%.*}
```

... e.g.:

```
$ dataset=foo.txt
$ nameis=${dataset%.*}
$ echo $nameis
foo
```

This syntax is described in the bash man page as:

> ${parameter%word}
>
> ${parameter%%word}
>
> Remove matching suffix pattern.  The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the result  of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the "%" case)  or  the  longest matching  pattern  (the "%%" case) deleted.  If parameter is @ or *, the pattern removal operation is  applied  to  each  positional  parameter  in  turn,  and the expansion is the resultant list.  If parameter is an array variable subscripted with  @  or *,  the  pattern  removal operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

Answer (score 5):

Now, if you want some stylish old-school regexp:

```
echo "foo.bar.tar.gz" | sed "s/^\(.*\)\..*$/\1/"
```

-> Shall return:  foo.bar.tar

```
I will break it down: 
s/   Substitute
^      From the beginning
\(     Mark
.*     Everything (greedy way)
\)     Stop Marking (the string marked goes to buffer 1)
\.     until a "." (which will be the last dot, because of the greedy selection)
.*     select everything (this is the extension that will be discarded)
$      until the end
/    With (substitute)
\1      The buffer 1 marked above (which is the filename before the last dot(.)
/    End
```

Cristiano Savino

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

You could remove everything following the last dot, if any, with `sed`:

```
nameis=$(echo $filename | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//')
```

But that would not work on files with double extensions such as `.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like `${dataset%.*}` might work; beware of files *without* extensions, though, as it will look for a dot that's not part of an extension to chop off.

Answer (score 1):

nameis=${dataset%%.*}
Assumes none of your basenames have a dot in it. This returns the longest possible dotless string from the left.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead of `basename` use `sed` command for that, like this:

`echo "$fileName" | sed 's/\..*$//g'`

Comment: That will fail for a file named, for example, `foo.bar.baz` if you want the result to be `foo.bar`.

Comment: This was quite good for me, as I did want the filename to be 'foo' unfortunately when the directory has a dot in it as well then it fails.